# Word Doc how do you have text on both sides of a word doc, where one side has multiple lines?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

The example would be a resume where my name would be on the left in 36pt and my email, linkedin, and phone number would be stacked on the right in size 10pt.

`JOHN DOE            email`
`JOHN DOE         linkedin`
`JOHN DOE        phone num`

Of course John Doe would not repeated 3 times, just once bigger

Comment: I would insert a table.  [Here's info on how to do it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-or-draw-a-table-a138f745-73ef-4879-b99a-2f3d38be612a).  Once the table is created, you can format it to add/remove borders, and make the text in the individual cells any size.  You could also just use three lines with a right-justified tab.  The first line would be "John Doe" Tab email return.  Then tab LinkedIn return, then Tab phone.

Comment: @Bandersnatch hey thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately because it is for a Resume it is not recommended to use table's because Applicant Tracking Systems (the internal software companies use to process digital resumes) are bad at reading tables. So I need to find a solution that does not use a table.

Comment: Ok, then I would just use right tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Type the paragraphs in their logical order:

> JOHN DOE
>   email
>   linkedin
>   phone num

Then do one of 2 things, depending on whether you're using a special paragraph style for the name:

- If the name is in a special paragraphs style that you're not using for anything else (e.g., **Title**), click the option to modify that style, and then, in the **Modify Style** dialog box, in the **Format** drop-down field, click **Frame**, and click **OK**. The 2nd, 3rd, and 4th paragraphs should now flow around the 1st. You can then adjust the frame settings, font sizes, and paragraph settings until everything looks the way you want.
- If the name isn't in a special paragraph style, or even if it is, select all 4 paragraphs, and then, on the **Layout** tab, click **Columns** > **Two**. You can then adjust the column widths, font sizes, and paragraph settings until everything looks the way you want.